# Boost Chat Server Example: expected type-specifier before 'sessiosn'

Tags: c++, networking, boost, client-server, boost-asio

Offending line:

```
  session_ptr new_session(new session(io_service_, room_));
```

(server.cpp, line 197)

Example I'm trying to follow:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html (Chat)

I removed all the "chat_" prexfixes from message, client, and server, because I'll be modifying it from a client / server chat into a distributed computing thinger.

Comment: But the exact boost example works for you? If you copy/pasted the error, seems like you wrote 'sesiosn' instead of 'sesion' in your code. If not, it could be anything. Could you point a link (or copy) your exact code here?

Answer (score 1):

You say you removed "chat_" from the `chat_session` declarations.  Unfortunately, that code uses "session" as a variable name.  You're probably seeing a conflict where the name "session" is being masked by a variable declaration.  (in `handle_accept`)  Try using "Session" or some other name instead.